# Create Local User with Custom User Folder in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-server-2008, profile, user-accounts

I am trying to create a new Win 2008 server local user and assign the user a different profile path.  I don't want Windows to generate all the files under C:\Users\newUser, instead, I'd like to have it do that in D:\customDir\newUser.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

So far this is what I have:

```
$users= @("U1","U2","U3")
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME,computer"
$group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME/MyCustomGroup,group"
$users | foreach {
    $userName = $_
    $userPath = "D:\customDir\$userName"
    echo "Creating $userName..."
    $user = $computer.Create("User",$userName)
    $user.put("description","User $userName Description")
    #$user.put("profilePath",$userPath) #This does not work, throws an error
    #$user.put("homeDirDrive","D:") #This appears to be ignored when uncommented
    $user.setpassword($userName)
    $user.setInfo()

    $group.add($user.Path)

    #run cmd from user account to create profile files/folders
    $spw = ConvertTo-SecureString $userName -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName,$spw
    Start-Process cmd /c -WindowStyle Hidden -Credential $cred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}
```

The script successfully creates the users and adds them to the custom group, but all the files/folders end up in C:\Users\U*

Comment: Could you include the error?

Comment: Exception calling "put" with "2" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000500F"
At line:1 char:1
+ $user.put("profilePath","d:\CustomDir\U1")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of for you would be to change it at the registry level. Note that I'm not recommending you mess with the registry, but this does do what you want -

The default directory for a new profile is determined by the ProfilesDirectory in HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList, and by default is %SystemDrive%\Users, changing it to $userpath should do what you want -

```
$regpath = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
$regname = "ProfilesDirectory"

set-itemproperty -path $regpath -name $regname -value $userpath
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: agree, this is what I ended up doing, even though it really feels like a hack.  Wish there was a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Agreed! Nothing elegant about chopping up the registry, too bad powershell doesn't handle local user preferences like it does AD. Not sure if this would help in your case, but I did notice this [module](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Local-Account-Management-a777191b). Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

To the OP,

Thanks for this piece, I was trying to figure out how to make this work for me:

## run cmd from user account to create profile files/folders

```
$spw = ConvertTo-SecureString $userName -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName,$spw
Start-Process cmd /c -WindowStyle Hidden -Credential $cred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

but I had to modify the last line to get it to work:

```
Start-Process cmd /c -Credential $cred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -LoadUserProfile
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine.

```
$loginName="ChrisMcCormack"
$newPass="123456ABCDEFG" # obviously generate a proper password...
$desc="average user"
$localHost=[ADSI]"WinNT://localhost"
$newUser=$localHost.Create("user",$loginName);
$newUser.setPassword($newPass);
$newUser.put("HomeDirectory","c:\users\$loginName");
$newUser.put("description",$desc);          
$newUser.setInfo();
```

You can also use:

```
$spw = ConvertTo-SecureString $newPass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $loginName,$spw
Start-Process cmd /c -WindowStyle Hidden -Credential $cred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

to create the users directories without logging the user on.

Chris

Comment: THIS!!! This a million times.  For anyone trying to get ssh to work on a windows cloud based deployment and finding that git cannot figure out where ~ is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I use according to the [underlaying COM component object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772213%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and the [IADsUser interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
$obj = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$user1=$obj.create("user", "utilisateur1")
$user1.PasswordExpired=0
$user1.Invoke("setpassword","test.2012")
$user1.Invoke("put", "HomeDirectory", "c:\silogix")
$user1.Invoke("put", "Profile", "c:\docs")
$user1.Invoke("put", "LoginScript", "test.cmd")
$user1.CommitChanges()
```

Here is the result.

[image]

Comment: This is equivalent to my script doing this: `$user.put("Profile", $userPath)` and `$user.put("HomeDirectory",$userPath)`.  HomeDirectory appears on the user's property, but when windows creates the profile folder, it still puts them under c:\Users\$userName, not under $userPath

Comment: This compleply normal. Even with roming profile, it exists a local profile, but when the user close his session, the profile is copied on the remote place.