# Create a local windows user using powershell to be used just as a service user to run services

Tags: windows, powershell-3.0

How to create a local user using powershell script.
The user should not be able to login. The purpose of this user is just to be assigned to run few services installed in the system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I use according to the [underlaying COM component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772213(v=VS.85).aspx) object model and the [IADsUser interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746340(v=vs.85).aspx). You must run it as administrator.

```
$obj = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$user1=$obj.create("user", "utilisateur1")
$user1.PasswordExpired=0
$user1.Invoke("setpassword","test.2012")
$user1.Invoke("put", "HomeDirectory", "c:\silogix")
$user1.Invoke("put", "Profile", "c:\docs")
$user1.Invoke("put", "LoginScript", "test.cmd")
$user1.CommitChanges()
```

You can see the result in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449856/608772). I just copy my answer because it's not a real duplicate.